# Having trouble using inner join sql command with Joomla query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, inner-join

I am attempting to use inner join to select the stop date of a user's subscription.  Here is the code sample:

```
Global $_CB_framework;
$myId = $_CB_framework->myId();

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$stopDateQuery = $db->getQuery(true);

$stopDateQuery->select($db->quoteName(array('#__cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id', '#__cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id', '#__cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date')));
$stopDateQuery->from($db->quoteName('#__cbsubs_subscriptions'));
$stopDateQuery->innerJoin($db->quoteName('#__cbsubs_payment_items' ON '#__cbsubs_subscriptions.id'='#__cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id'));
$stopDateQuery->where($db->quoteName('#__cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id')." = ".$db->quote($myId));


$db->setQuery($stopDateQuery);

$stopDateQueryResults = $db->loadRow();

$stopDate = $stopDateQueryResults['2'];

echo 'stop Date:'.$stopDate;
```

I have run the statement directly into phpMyAdmin and the table will join with no problem.  I am sure that it has something to do with my formatting of the statement.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Since this question is entirely specific to Joomla, this page seems a good candidate to migrate to https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innerJoin line has syntax errors. Change to:

```
$stopDateQuery->innerJoin($db->quoteName('#__cbsubs_payment_items') . ' ON #__cbsubs_subscriptions.id = #__cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id');
```

`innerJoin()` takes a string which should be in the format of an SQL join without the join type. for example:

```
$obj->innerJoin('table_a on table_a.id = table_b.id');
```